# iOS & Android - Location contains coordinates

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, range, core-location

Is there any way to see, if certain coordinates are included in a CLPlaceMark?

More specifically, after I get user's A location and know in which city he/she is, I need to have another user's B coordinates and check whether they're part of user's A city...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just compare placemarkA.locality == placemarkB.locality?

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Because my app is in iOS and android, using CoreLocation and Google maps accordingly... So, the locality is often slightly different...

Comment: Got it.  Might want to update your tags to indicate Android.

Answer (score 0):

Were would you be doing the compare?  The google geocoding / reverse geocoding api is available for android, ios, and a simple web api.  If you use the **same service** for all clients, that should provide a consistent location name which you could to check if any two users are in the same city.

It would probably be simplest to just use the [web api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) for all cases.

Comment: Doesn't it have a request limit?

Comment: yeah they do, but I think they are pretty generous, 150,000 per day  (after identity verification) for the android/ios clients and 2500 per day for the web.  So yeah if your app gets really popular you might have to shell out some.

Comment: Sorry, the android client is charged as well? I thought Google had its service free for the android!!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details  I think you would need the places api, which is 150K free requests per day.  If you need more than that then you probably have a very successful app.

Comment: The thing we need is geocoding... and the request limit for that is 2.500 per day... So it can easily be passed! :/

Comment: No, if you do the decoding on the using the ios and android client, it's 150K per day.  it's 2500 for the web api.  Any I think this answers your current question.  Geo coding/decoding is not a trivial service,  I don't think you will find any service that is totally unlimited and totally free.